# How to select students with marks in all three subjects less then 100?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I came across this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/conXR.png)

Here is my response to it, I just started myself learning SQL recently.

```
Select a.roll_number
     , a.name
     , b.roll_number 
  from student_information a
  join examination_marks b
    on a.roll_number = b.roll_number
 Group 
    by roll_number
 Having Sum(subject_one.examination_marks + subject_two.examination_marks + subject_three.examination_marks) < 100;
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Have you created the tables and inserted data? Does your query return the correct result?

Comment: `roll_number` is a primary key in both tables, so it's a 1:1 relation. That means you don't need to group, just add.

Comment: On a side note: The idea with alias names is that they shall make the query more readable. Arbitrary alias names like `a` and `b` rather do the opposite. Use mnemonic names instead, e.g. `si` or `i` for `student_information` and `em` or `m` for `examination_marks`.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Alejandro

Go through this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/conXR.png

Comment: @user9446396 Seems like the same image as in the post. That's just a task you have, not a question for the site. Seems like you've done some code for it, but what question do you have about that?

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above say, 2), the correct response is to reject the premise of the question.

Comment: A quick sidenote: ideally you would copy the whole problem into your question, or the relevant parts. Referencing an external image makes it harder to follow your question and see what you've already done. 

Notes on your SQL: 
Use readable aliases (STUDENTS, MARKS). 
No need to select the roll_number twice. 
Drop the group by unless you would expect there to be multiple rows per student_id. My read is each student has one row and the marks are their total for that subject on the test. Change that HAVING to a WHERE.

Comment: Please tag only a single RDBMS and ensure your question has all the relevant data (not in images, not in comments). And include sample data + expected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need not to group by your result since there should be one row in each table for every roll_number.
You did the join right. Now just replace group by and having clause with where condition to check whether sum of all three subject's number is less then 100 or not. If it less then hundred then select roll_number and name.

```
Select a.roll_number, a.name 
from student_information a
inner join
examination_marks b
       on a.roll_number = b.roll_number
where (subject_one + subject_two + subject_three )< 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the student information using the following query.

```
Select std.roll_number, std.name 
from student_information std
join examination_marks exm
on std.roll_number = exm.roll_number
where (subject_one + subject_two + subject_three) < 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT STD.ROLL_NUMBER,STD.NAME 
FROM STUDENT_INFORMATION STD,EXAMINATION_MARKS 
 EXM 
Group by STD.ROLL_NUMBER=EXM.ROLL_NUMBER 
  Having SUM(EXM.SUBJECT_ONE+EXM.SUBJECT_TWO+EXM.SUBJECT_THREE)<100;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: pretty sure this logic is not the logic the question is asking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT STD.ROLL_NUMBER,STD.NAME 
FROM STUDENT_INFORMATION AS STD,EXAMINATION_MARKS AS EXM 
WHERE STD.ROLL_NUMBER=EXM.ROLL_NUMBER 
  AND (EXM.SUBJECT_ONE+EXM.SUBJECT_TWO+EXM.SUBJECT_THREE)<100;
```

Comment: You really should be writing explicit JOINS instead of the older implicit join syntax these days.

Comment: Please add an explanation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33601897)